# How to create an instance of class that takes interface as its constructor parameter using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
object[] parame = new object[1];
parameters[0] = param1;

ConstructorInfo[] info = type.GetConstructors();
info[0].Invoke(parame );

obj= Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameters);
```

This gives me error saying `ctor` not found because the `ctor` takes interface as a parameter.

How to create an instance of this object now?

```
public Controller(ICustomInterface custom)
        {
            _custom= custom;
        }
```

I tried to invoke the ctor with same param and it says object of this class cannot be converted to Interface type. Though this class implemnets this interface.

Comment: parameters should be object of class which implements the interface. in your case parameter is just object which is the problem.

Comment: I tried with this. I passed the parameter as an object that implements that interface. But still show that error.

Comment: Does this class only have one constructor? You are looking at `info[0]` - could you be invoking the wrong constructor?

Comment: @Virus: Please show that code.

Comment: Can you give the code for class and the param class which implements the interface?

Comment: @Charleh - yes it has only one ctor

Comment: Can you show your ctor?

Comment: updated the question with ctor

Comment: and the param1 is an object of the class that implements this interface

Comment: I've dropped my answer. The OP needs to clarify himself about what he's looking for. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Yes. To do this i created an instance of class that implements the interface and passed this instance as a paramter. Am I doing right here?

Comment: Are you sure that `type` referes to the `Controller` type ?

Answer (score 2):

Having implemetation of your interface, so that you can create instance, that implements interface, like this:

```
class CustomClass : ICustomInterface {}
```

you simply call `Activator` as

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Controller), new CustomClass());
```

It will return a correct instance of `Contoller`, with `new CustomClass()` being passed as constructor argument